# Migrate SQL Server question turned into Management Studio question to Server Fault

Tags: support, specific-question

Can somebody migrate this SO question to ServerFault. Or should I just delete it and retype it? There's already activity on it.

[Turn off display of header dashes in SQL Server Management Studio query results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4227487/)

This question was originally framed as SQL Server but it appears to be a Management Studio question instead - and that's more in the domain of Server Fault as I see it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nah. It's allowed on Stack Overflow.

From the FAQ:

> What kind of questions can I ask here?
>
> (...)
>
> - software tools commonly used by programmers